# How to insert variable value into URL using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read from a file "csv" that contains keywords and insert that into URL : https://google.com
https://www.google.com/search?q=**Exapmle**
So I can search via google and get the results with my loop , for example I have 5 keywords inside this file:csv_2023.csv , that means I should send 5 request and get 5 response
This is my code:

```
import re
import requests
import csv
with open("./csv_2023.csv", 'r') as file:
  csvreader = csv.reader(file)
  for row in csvreader:
   
url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q=csvreader'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
regex_pattern = 'PDF'
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
match = re.findall(regex_pattern, result.text) 
print(match)
```

I have used "f" string before the URL but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `params` option to `requests.get()` to specify the URL parameters.

```
import re
import requests
import csv

url = f'https://www.google.com/search'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
regex_pattern = 'PDF'

with open("./csv_2023.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in csvreader:        
        result = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params={"q": row[0]})
        match = re.findall(regex_pattern, result.text) 
        print(match)
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked but why you did not use : https://www.google.com/search?q=

Comment: Because the `q` key in `params` adds `q=` itself.

Comment: I see , what if the URL hasn't have q=  , for example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75933899/  and I want to change the questions number : 75933899

Comment: In that case you need to use string concatenation or formatting. This code is specifically for Google search queries.

Comment: Could you please write that, because I have the same case but the URL has no q= , Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no generic solution, every solution will be specific to the type of URL you need to create.

Answer (score -1):

The proper way to use f-Strings in python is like: `f'abc{3**2}'` => that would be interpreted as `abc9`. So, in your case:

```
import re
import requests
import csv
with open("./csv_2023.csv", 'r') as file:
  csvreader = csv.reader(file)
  for row in csvreader:
    url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={row}'
    regex_pattern = 'PDF'
    result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    match = re.findall(regex_pattern, result.text) 
    print(match)
```

Comment: `row` is a list, that won't work.

Comment: This doesn't do proper URL encoding of special characters.